# Are Alexandrescu's Ideas relevant with modern C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm starting to read Alexandrescu's modern c++ design and I'm interested in following question. Are ideas described in this book still relevant with modern C++?

Comment: @herohuyongtao I would probably read C++17 as "post c++14, with at least concepts-lite added."  Wikipedia already has an article on it.

Comment: C++1z is less ,,, ambitiously specific.

Answer (score 3):

The ideas are certainly relevant and the principles and techniques Andrei describes are still valid. Probably some if not all the examples would be written differently now, to exploit language elements that were not available when he wrote the book.

Actually some of the ideas he presents in his book have been included in the current standard, even if in a different form.